# Monogame Windows Phone 8

Tags: xna, monogame, windows-phone-8

I want to port a WP7 XNA game to WP8 using MonoGame. The thing is that I have Windows 7. So here's the questions (if some sound dumb, please bare with me).

- Do I need to have Windows 8?
- Do I need to have the Windows Phone SDK 8?
- How do I get the templates for Visual Studio so I can create a project for WP8?

I'm kinda newbie into this monogame thingy. I've been using XNA for quite a while.

Comment: How do you plan to test it without access to a Windows 8 phone?

Comment: I have a windows phone 8 but not a windows 8. It's just that i have never used mono before and the information i found to make a port to windows phone 8 is kinda messy

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need both Windows 8 and the Windows Phone SDK, a detailed tutorial describing how to setup up MonoGame for WP8 (written by a Microsoft Employee) can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tarawalker/archive/2012/12/04/windows-8-game-development-using-c-xna-and-monogame-3-0-building-a-shooter-game-walkthrough-part-1-overview-installation-monogame-3-0-project-creation.aspx)

Edit: There is (supposedly) a way to install the Windows Phone SDK on Windows 7 ( described [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2422751) ) but it is not officially supported by Microsoft and therefore not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Thanks for the links. :D . Great information's in there. I'll let you know how everything went